# Google charts groups getvalue()

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, getselection

http://jsfiddle.net/dcw2qq/828pkn6w/

I am trying to obtain the select value when I click on the main Pie chart individual Slices (pieChart). Right now it is firing a the select Listener just fine, but it is not distinguishing between the different categories. I have been muddy through this API for about a week with novice JS experience, so this may be a simple solution. The function in question starts at Line 285.

Please look at my JS fiddle for the code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);


      function drawDashboard() {


        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

         data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
         data.addColumn('string', 'Description');
         data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
         data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');



         data.addRows([
                [new Date(2010, 6, 13),'CRATE AND BARREL #344', 'Merchandise',{v: 232.00, f: '$232.00'}],
              [new Date(2010, 4, 4),'HILTON HOTELS', 'Lodging', {v: 252.99, f: '$252.99'}],
              [new Date(2010, 0, 22),'LIBERTY VETERINARY RICHMOND VA', 'Other',{v: 56.23, f: '$56.23'}],
              [new Date(2010, 9, 6),'REGAL SHORT PUMP RICHMOND VA', 'Entertainment',{v: 24.50, f: '$24.50'}],
              [new Date(2010, 0, 17),'RICHMOND TIMES DISPATCH', 'Other',{v: 18.00, f: '$18.00'}],
              [new Date(2010, 7, 12),'MARRIOTT RICHMOND VA', 'Lodging',{v: 645.67, f: '$645.67'}],
              [new Date(2010, 5, 23),'HERTZ RENT-A-CAR', 'Car Rental', {v: 105.12, f: '$105.12'}],
              [new Date(2010, 10, 5),'TURKEY HILL RICHMOND VA', 'Dinning',{v: 45.03, f: '$45.03'}],
              [new Date(2010, 0, 8),'WAWAGAS', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 56.00, f: '$56.00'}],
              [new Date(2010, 6, 10),'JIFFYLUBE', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 109.78, f: '$109.78'}],
              [new Date(2010, 6, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 876.23, f: '$876.23'}],
              [new Date(2010, 7, 25),'MUAY THAI', 'Dinning', {v: 19.34, f: '$19.34'}],
              [new Date(2010, 2, 22),'JCPENNY', 'Merchandise',{v: 102.22, f: '$102.22'}],
              [new Date(2010, 1, 25),'BASS PRO SHOP', 'Merchandise',{v: 309.76, f: '$309.76'}],
              [new Date(2010, 3, 4),'CVS PHARMACY', 'Merchandise', {v: 3.21, f: '$3.21'}],
              [new Date(2010, 10, 13),'WILD WINGS CAFE', 'Dinning',{v: 25.87, f: '$25.87'}],
              [new Date(2010, 6, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 923.55, f: '$923.55'}],
              [new Date(2010, 7, 24),'CAFE MENCINA', 'Merchandise',{v: 98.56, f: '$98.56'}],
              [new Date(2010, 3, 27),'WAWA GAS', 'Gas/Automotive', {v: 57.00, f: '$57.00'}],
              [new Date(2010, 9, 16),'RITZ CARLTON', 'Lodging',{v: 456.12, f: '$456.12'}],

              [new Date(2011, 6, 16),'CRATE AND BARREL #644', 'Merchandise',{v: 292.00, f: '$292.00'}],
              [new Date(2011, 8, 8),'HILTON HOTELS', 'Lodging', {v: 252.99, f: '$252.99'}],
              [new Date(2011, 0, 22),'LIBERTY VETERINARY RICHMOND VA', 'Other',{v: 56.26, f: '$56.26'}],
              [new Date(2011, 9, 6),'REGAL SHORT PUMP RICHMOND VA', 'Entertainment',{v: 28.50, f: '$28.50'}],
              [new Date(2011, 0, 17),'RICHMOND TIMES DISPATCH', 'Other',{v: 18.00, f: '$18.00'}],
              [new Date(2011, 7, 12),'MARRIOTT RICHMOND VA', 'Lodging',{v: 685.67, f: '$685.67'}],
              [new Date(2011, 5, 26),'HERTZ RENT-A-CAR', 'Car Rental', {v: 105.12, f: '$105.12'}],
              [new Date(2011, 10, 5),'TURKEY HILL RICHMOND VA', 'Dinning',{v: 85.06, f: '$85.06'}],
              [new Date(2011, 0, 8),'WAWAGAS', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 56.00, f: '$56.00'}],
              [new Date(2011, 6, 10),'JIFFYLUBE', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 109.78, f: '$109.78'}],
              [new Date(2011, 6, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 876.26, f: '$876.26'}],
              [new Date(2011, 7, 25),'MUAY THAI', 'Dinning', {v: 19.68, f: '$19.68'}],
              [new Date(2011, 2, 22),'JCPENNY', 'Merchandise',{v: 102.22, f: '$102.22'}],
              [new Date(2011, 1, 25),'BASS PRO SHOP', 'Merchandise',{v: 609.76, f: '$609.76'}],
              [new Date(2011, 6, 8),'CVS PHARMACY', 'Merchandise', {v: 6.21, f: '$6.21'}],
              [new Date(2011, 10, 16),'WILD WINGS CAFE', 'Dinning',{v: 25.87, f: '$25.87'}],
              [new Date(2011, 6, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 926.55, f: '$926.55'}],
              [new Date(2011, 7, 28),'CAFE MENCINA', 'Merchandise',{v: 98.56, f: '$98.56'}],
              [new Date(2011, 6, 27),'WAWA GAS', 'Gas/Automotive', {v: 57.00, f: '$57.00'}],
              [new Date(2011, 9, 16),'RITZ CARLTON', 'Lodging',{v: 856.12, f: '$856.12'}],

              [new Date(2012, 2, 12),'CRATE AND BARREL #244', 'Merchandise',{v: 292.00, f: '$292.00'}],
              [new Date(2012, 8, 8),'HILTON HOTELS', 'Lodging', {v: 252.99, f: '$252.99'}],
              [new Date(2012, 0, 22),'LIBERTY VETERINARY RICHMOND VA', 'Other',{v: 52.22, f: '$52.22'}],
              [new Date(2012, 9, 2),'REGAL SHORT PUMP RICHMOND VA', 'Entertainment',{v: 28.50, f: '$28.50'}],
              [new Date(2012, 0, 17),'RICHMOND TIMES DISPATCH', 'Other',{v: 18.00, f: '$18.00'}],
              [new Date(2012, 7, 12),'MARRIOTT RICHMOND VA', 'Lodging',{v: 285.27, f: '$285.27'}],
              [new Date(2012, 5, 22),'HERTZ RENT-A-CAR', 'Car Rental', {v: 105.12, f: '$105.12'}],
              [new Date(2012, 10, 5),'TURKEY HILL RICHMOND VA', 'Dinning',{v: 85.02, f: '$85.02'}],
              [new Date(2012, 0, 8),'WAWAGAS', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 52.00, f: '$52.00'}],
              [new Date(2012, 2, 10),'JIFFYLUBE', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 109.78, f: '$109.78'}],
              [new Date(2012, 2, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 872.22, f: '$872.22'}],
              [new Date(2012, 7, 25),'MUAY THAI', 'Dinning', {v: 19.28, f: '$19.28'}],
              [new Date(2012, 2, 22),'JCPENNY', 'Merchandise',{v: 102.22, f: '$102.22'}],
              [new Date(2012, 1, 25),'BASS PRO SHOP', 'Merchandise',{v: 209.72, f: '$209.72'}],
              [new Date(2012, 2, 8),'CVS PHARMACY', 'Merchandise', {v: 2.21, f: '$2.21'}],
              [new Date(2012, 10, 12),'WILD WINGS CAFE', 'Dinning',{v: 25.87, f: '$25.87'}],
              [new Date(2012, 2, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 922.55, f: '$922.55'}],
              [new Date(2012, 7, 28),'CAFE MENCINA', 'Merchandise',{v: 98.52, f: '$98.52'}],
              [new Date(2012, 2, 27),'WAWA GAS', 'Gas/Automotive', {v: 57.00, f: '$57.00'}],
              [new Date(2012, 9, 12),'RITZ CARLTON', 'Lodging',{v: 852.12, f: '$852.12'}],

              [new Date(2013, 2, 12),'CRATE AND BARREL #244', 'Merchandise',{v: 222.00, f: '$222.00'}],
              [new Date(2013, 8, 8),'HILTON HOTELS', 'Lodging', {v: 252.22, f: '$252.22'}],
              [new Date(2013, 0, 22),'LIBERTY VETERINARY RICHMOND VA', 'Other',{v: 52.22, f: '$52.22'}],
              [new Date(2013, 2, 2),'REGAL SHORT PUMP RICHMOND VA', 'Entertainment',{v: 28.50, f: '$28.50'}],
              [new Date(2013, 0, 17),'RICHMOND TIMES DISPATCH', 'Other',{v: 18.00, f: '$18.00'}],
              [new Date(2013, 7, 12),'MARRIOTT RICHMOND VA', 'Lodging',{v: 285.27, f: '$285.27'}],
              [new Date(2013, 5, 22),'HERTZ RENT-A-CAR', 'Car Rental', {v: 105.12, f: '$105.12'}],
              [new Date(2013, 10, 5),'TURKEY HILL RICHMOND VA', 'Dinning',{v: 85.02, f: '$85.02'}],
              [new Date(2013, 0, 8),'WAWAGAS', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 52.00, f: '$52.00'}],
              [new Date(2013, 2, 10),'JIFFYLUBE', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 102.78, f: '$102.78'}],
              [new Date(2013, 2, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 872.22, f: '$872.22'}],
              [new Date(2013, 7, 25),'MUAY THAI', 'Dinning', {v: 12.28, f: '$12.28'}],
              [new Date(2013, 2, 22),'JCPENNY', 'Merchandise',{v: 102.22, f: '$102.22'}],
              [new Date(2013, 1, 25),'BASS PRO SHOP', 'Merchandise',{v: 202.72, f: '$202.72'}],
              [new Date(2013, 2, 8),'CVS PHARMACY', 'Merchandise', {v: 2.21, f: '$2.21'}],
              [new Date(2013, 10, 12),'WILD WINGS CAFE', 'Dinning',{v: 25.87, f: '$25.87'}],
              [new Date(2013, 2, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 222.55, f: '$222.55'}],
              [new Date(2013, 7, 28),'CAFE MENCINA', 'Merchandise',{v: 28.52, f: '$28.52'}],
              [new Date(2013, 2, 27),'WAWA GAS', 'Gas/Automotive', {v: 57.00, f: '$57.00'}],
              [new Date(2013, 2, 12),'RITZ CARLTON', 'Lodging',{v: 852.12, f: '$852.12'}],

              [new Date(2014, 2, 12),'CRATE AND BARREL #244', 'Merchandise',{v: 222.00, f: '$222.00'}],
              [new Date(2014, 8, 3),'HILTON HOTELS', 'Lodging', {v: 252.22, f: '$252.22'}],
              [new Date(2014, 0, 22),'LIBERTY VETERINARY RICHMOND VA', 'Other',{v: 52.22, f: '$52.22'}],
              [new Date(2014, 2, 2),'REGAL SHORT PUMP RICHMOND VA', 'Entertainment',{v: 23.50, f: '$23.50'}],
              [new Date(2014, 0, 17),'RICHMOND TIMES DISPATCH', 'Other',{v: 13.00, f: '$13.00'}],
              [new Date(2014, 7, 12),'MARRIOTT RICHMOND VA', 'Lodging',{v: 235.27, f: '$235.27'}],
              [new Date(2014, 5, 22),'HERTZ RENT-A-CAR', 'Car Rental', {v: 105.12, f: '$105.12'}],
              [new Date(2014, 10, 5),'TURKEY HILL RICHMOND VA', 'Dinning',{v: 35.02, f: '$35.02'}],
              [new Date(2014, 0, 3),'WAWAGAS', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 52.00, f: '$52.00'}],
              [new Date(2014, 2, 10),'JIFFYLUBE', 'Gas/Automotive',{v: 102.73, f: '$102.73'}],
              [new Date(2014, 2, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 372.22, f: '$372.22'}],
              [new Date(2014, 7, 25),'MUAY THAI', 'Dinning', {v: 12.23, f: '$12.23'}],
              [new Date(2014, 2, 22),'JCPENNY', 'Merchandise',{v: 102.22, f: '$102.22'}],
              [new Date(2014, 1, 25),'BASS PRO SHOP', 'Merchandise',{v: 202.72, f: '$202.72'}],
              [new Date(2014, 2, 3),'CVS PHARMACY', 'Merchandise', {v: 2.21, f: '$2.21'}],
              [new Date(2014, 10, 12),'WILD WINGS CAFE', 'Dinning',{v: 25.37, f: '$25.37'}],
              [new Date(2014, 2, 22),'DELTA AIRLINES', 'Airfare',{v: 222.55, f: '$222.55'}],
              [new Date(2014, 7, 23),'CAFE MENCINA', 'Merchandise',{v: 23.52, f: '$23.52'}],
              [new Date(2014, 2, 27),'WAWA GAS', 'Gas/Automotive', {v: 57.00, f: '$57.00'}],
              [new Date(2014, 2, 12),'RITZ CARLTON', 'Lodging',{v: 352.12, f: '$352.12'}]


        ]);


        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0,1,2,3,{
                       calc: mas,
                       type: 'string',

            }])
              function mas(view2,row) {
                  var a = view2.getValue(row,2);
                  return a;
              }




        var dateRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div',
          'options': {
             'filterColumnLabel': 'Date',
             'ui': { 'format': { 'pattern': 'yyyy' } },
          }
        });



    var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'control2',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Category',
        'filterColumnIndex':2,
        'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': false
        }
      },
     //'state': {'selectedValues': ['Gas/Automotive', 'Lodging','Merchandise']}
    });


    var categoryPicker2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'control3',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Category',
        'filterColumnIndex':1,
        'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': false
        }
      },
     //'state': {'selectedValues': ['Gas/Automotive', 'Lodging','Merchandise']}
    });




        var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'PieChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',
          'options': {
            'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
            'pieSliceBorderColor': 'transparent',
            'chartArea':{
                'left':130,
                'top':-100,
                'width':1000,
                'height':1000,
                'backgroundColor':'transparent',
              },  
            'width': 600,
            'height': 600,
            'is3D':true,
            'pieSliceText':'none',
            'legend':{
                'position': 'right',
                'alignment':'center',
                'textStyle': {
                    'color': 'blue',
                    'fontSize': 14
                    }
                }

          }
        });




        var pieChart2 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'PieChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div2',
          'options': {
            'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
            'pieSliceBorderColor': 'transparent',
            'chartArea':{
                'left':130,
                'top':-100,
                'width':300,
                'height':300,
                'backgroundColor':'transparent',
              },  
            'width': 300,
            'height': 300,
            'is3D':true,
            'pieSliceText':'none',
            'legend':{
                'position': 'none',
                'alignment':'center',
                'textStyle': {
                    'color': 'blue',
                    'fontSize': 14
                    }
                }

          }
        });










        var tableChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'Table',
          'containerId': 'table_div',
          'options': {

          }
        });







                   function selectHandler() {
                      var dt = tableChart.getDataTable();
                      var catGroup = google.visualization.data.group(dt, [{
                                          type:'string',
                                          label:dt.getColumnLabel(2),
                                          column: 2,



                                          }],[{
                                              type: 'number',
                                              label: dt.getColumnLabel(3),
                                              column: 3,                                                
                                              aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum

                                              }
                                          ]);

                          alert('The user selected ' + catGroup.getValue(3,0));
                          //window.open(url,'_self');
                        //}
                    }


                    function updatePieCharts() {
                        var dt = tableChart.getDataTable();




                                      // DRAWS THE PIE CHARTS
                                      var catGroup = google.visualization.data.group(dt, [{
                                          type:'string',
                                          label:dt.getColumnLabel(2),
                                          column: 2,



                                          }],[{
                                              type: 'number',
                                              label: dt.getColumnLabel(3),
                                              column: 3,                                                
                                              aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum

                                              }
                                          ]);
                                          pieChart.setDataTable(catGroup);
                                          formatter.format(catGroup, 1);                    
                                          pieChart.draw();


                                          // DRAWS THE PIE CHARTS
                                      var catGroup2 = google.visualization.data.group(dt, [{
                                          type:'string',
                                          label:dt.getColumnLabel(1),
                                          column: 1,



                                          }],[{
                                              type: 'number',
                                              label: dt.getColumnLabel(3),
                                              column: 3,                                                
                                              aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum

                                              }
                                          ]);
                                          pieChart2.setDataTable(catGroup2);
                                          formatter.format(catGroup2, 1);                   
                                          pieChart2.draw();

                    }



google.visualization.events.addListener(pieChart, 'select', selectHandler);


google.visualization.events.addListener(tableChart, 'ready', updatePieCharts); 







        /*function changeRangeOf(e,days) {
            //setActiveState();
            var timeframe = e
            $('.chart-nav button.btn').removeClass('active');
            $('#changeRange'+timeframe).addClass('active');


            //setPieChart Range();
            var today = new Date();
            today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            const monthLength = (24*(days)) * 60 * 60 * 1000;       
            var ago = new Date(today.getTime() - monthLength);

         
            //Redraw Pie Chart();

            dateRangeSlider.setState({lowValue: ago, highValue: today});
            dateRangeSlider.draw();

        }
         $("#changeRangeMo").click(function(){changeRangeOf('Mo',30)});
         $("#changeRange3Mo").click(function(){changeRangeOf('3Mo',90)});
         $("#changeRange6Mo").click(function(){changeRangeOf('6Mo',180)}); 
         $("#changeRange12Mo").click(function(){changeRangeOf('12Mo',365)}); 
         $("#changeRange24Mo").click(function(){changeRangeOf('24Mo',730)}); 
         $("#changeRange36Mo").click(function(){changeRangeOf('36Mo',1095)}); 
         $("#changeRange48Mo").click(function(){changeRangeOf('48Mo',1460)});
         $("#changeRangeYTD").click(function(){changeRangeOf('YTD',9999)}) */

         // Create a dashboard.
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

        // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
        // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
        // given the chosen slider range.
        dashboard.bind([dateRangeSlider,categoryPicker,categoryPicker2],tableChart);





        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
                              {prefix: '$',fractionDigits: 2});
                               formatter.format(data,3); // Apply formatter to second column

            var formatter_short = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: " MM/dd/yyyy"});
        formatter_short.format(data, 0);


        dashboard.draw(view);



      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>


     <button class="reset" >Reset</button>                 
      <button id="changeRangeMo" class="btn" >1 month</button>
      <button id="changeRange3Mo" class="btn" >3 months</button>
      <button id="changeRange6Mo" class="btn" >6 months</button>
      <button id="changeRange12Mo" class="btn" >12 months</button>
      <button id="changeRange24Mo" class="btn" >24 months</button>
      <button id="changeRange36Mo" class="btn" >36 months</button>
      <button id="changeRange48Mo" class="btn" >48 months</button>
      <button id="changeRangeYTD" class="btn active">YTD</button> 

    <div id="dashboard_div">
      <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
      <div id="filter_div"></div>
      <div id="control2"></div>
      <div id="control3"></div>


      <div id="chart_div" ></div>
      <div id="chart_div2"></div>



      <div id="table_div"></div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this the behavior you are after? http://jsfiddle.net/828pkn6w/2/